# If $f\in \mathbb{R}[X]$, then do only real numbers count as roots of $f$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, terminology, definition, roots

I had an argument with a friend about this and I would like to know what you think. If we are given a polynomial $f\in \mathbb{R}[X]$, then do only real numbers count as roots of $f$?
Let me give you an example. Let's say we are given the polynomial $f=X^2+1 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$. It is obvious that $f(i)=f(-i)=0$, but are $i$ and $-i$ considered to be roots of $f$ since they are not in $\mathbb{R}$? I think that they are not and they would be only if we were told that $f\in \mathbb{C}[X]$.
EDIT: After the discussion in the comments, I came to the conclusion that a polynomial whose coefficients are in a field can also have roots in another field. Can you give me some examples of this occuring in polynomials which are not in $\mathbb{Z}[X],\mathbb{Q}[X],\mathbb{R}[X]$?

Comment: It depends on the context. You just as likely to find a handout, a section of a book or an article where the author is interested in having real polynomials and in considering their complex roots, as you are of finding some where the author is interested in their real roots alone. I presume you might not be as likely to find sources treating the real roots of complex polynomials.

Comment: Whenever you speak of the roots of a polynomial you should specify what field you have in mind.

Comment: Usually, if we speak of the roots of a polynomial with real coefficients without specifying that we only consider the real roots, the non-real roots are considered as well.

Comment: By you logic the only roots in $\mathbb Z[x]$ (polynomial with integer coefficients) would be integer roots.  But many text and contexts assume that our "universe" is only the real numbers.  But when so, we apply it to *everything*; not just roots of polynomials.

Comment: .... Or to clarify. It isn't the specification of the coefficients that determine the specification of roots to allow.

Comment: Thank you ! I drew my conclusion from the following definition in my textbook : "Let $f \in K[X]$ ($(K,+, \cdot)$ is a commutative field). An element $\alpha \in K$ is a root of $f$ if $f(\alpha)=0$". This is why I thought that we should only be considering real roots in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are talking to someone that has never been exposed to complex numbers, when you ask what are the roots of $p(x)\in\mathbb R[x]$, then most of the time (outside Real Analysis) it is implicit that you mean the *complex* roots. If you are interested only on real (or integer or whatever), you should state that explicitely.